# select multiple excel range using c#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

What is wrong with the below code?

```
wsht.Range["H:I, K:L, AD:AE, AG, AI, AK, AM, AQ, AV"].NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
```

Purpose is to set numberformat in non-consecutive columns.

Answer (score 0):

okk...I got where I was wrong.
The line should be:

```
wsht.Range["H:I, K:L, AD:AE, AG:AG, AI:AI, AK:AK, AM:AM, AQ:AQ, AV:AV"].NumberFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss";
```

Because I did not mention proper range AG:AG previously, there was error.